Snowflake warehouse access issue inside stored procedure
I have written a stored procedure that runs multiple queries with select and show keywords. This stored procedure executes as the caller.
This is a sample query that I am running:
 sq := 'SHOW FUTURE GRANTS IN DATABASE ' || :database_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sq);
    future_obj := (SELECT OBJECT_AGG(REPLACE("grant_on" ||'S','_',' '),TO_VARIANT(UPPER("grantee_name")))  
                    FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) 
                    WHERE "privilege" = 'OWNERSHIP' AND "grant_to" = 'ROLE' GROUP BY "grant_to");

When I run the stored procedure where I have only one warehouse, it runs perfectly fine, but when I run the same script where we have multiple warehouses, I get the error shown here.
How I can pass the warehouse, I have tried to execute 'USE WAREHOUSE ' but it also not working.
I am running this stored procedure with the Accountadmin role. It requires running with the same role and the AccountAdmin role already has default warehouse configured.

Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 166 at position 15: No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.


Hi - please update your question with the complete SP (it can be a minimal version). Is the SP being executed as owner or caller? What’s the warehouse context when you call the SP? Does the ACCOUNTADMIN role have a default warehouse set?

SP is executed as Caller not Owner, Yes default warehouse is configured to account admin. I have updated the question as well.

There is not much to go on in your inquiry as you've omitted all pieces of information to the warehouse selection. When you put your next post up here I recommend humbly that you include all code, with parts hashed if you're worried about putting it out there. But you should also include where you're calling the SP from, how you're doing it - and possibly even data from the query history that shows the query profile.
There are many different reasons why you can get this error message. I would humbly request that you do this:
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN
USE WAREHOUSE <WAREHOUSENAME>

CALL <THE STORED PROCEDURE YOU HAVE>

It looks likely that the session that is calling the procedure does not have a warehouse selected. If it's a worksheet that was created before you selected an default warehouse, it's not going to be selected int he worksheet unless you explicitly select it. Please try this, and if this fails, add more information. I'm sure we can sort this out quick if you just give us all the context instead of keeping us looking through a small keyhole here.
If it was a problem with the warehouse not being started, it would simply say that the warehouse is suspended, not that you don't have one selected.
